# vue.js 2 list of objects in component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm very new to js frontend frameworks, and I'm trying to learn some vue.js.

In particular I'm trying to render an array of `Note` objects that have an `id`, `description` and `date` attributes.

I'm trying to do all of this in a component :)

My `ul` element looks like

```js
<ul class="list-group">
  <li
    is="note-item"
    v-for="note in notesList"
    v-bind:title="note.description"
    :key="note.id"
  ></li>
</ul>
```

And my Vue code looks like:
Some notes:

I run on page load `vue.updateNoteList` which calls `vue.loadFirstNote`.

```js
Vue.component('note-item', {
  template: '\
    <li>\
      {{ note.description }}\
      <button v-on:click="$emit(\'remove\')">X</button>\
    </li>\
  ',
  props: ['notesList']
});

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#main-content',
  data: {
    input: '',
    notesList: [{ }]
  },

  methods: {
    updateNoteList: function (callback) {
      const that = this;
      Note.all((notes) => {
        that.notesList = notes;
        return callback();
      });
    },

    loadFirstNote: function () {
      if (this.notesList.length > 0) {
      this.note = this.notesList[0];
    }
  }
});
```

I've been trying to get this working all day, and I'm getting nowhere. I'm getting the following console errors. Any help would be appreciated.

```
vue.common.js?e881:519 [Vue warn]: Property or method "note" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. 
vue.common.js?e881:519 [Vue warn]: Error when rendering component <note-item>:
vue.common.js?e881:2961 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two errors in your code

1. you are trying to use note in your component, but you have not passed it as props in that component, you have `notesList` which you dont use in view.
2. You have use `\` in `$emit`, which is not required

Following are these fixes:

**HTML**:

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li
    is="note-item"
    v-for="note in notesList"
    v-bind:title="note.description"
    :key="note.id"
    :note="note" 
  ></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**:

```
 Vue.component('note-item', {
  template: '\
    <li>\
      {{ note.description }}\
      <button v-on:click="$emit('remove')">X</button>\
    </li>\
  ',
  props: ['note']
});

const vm = new Vue({
  el: '#main-content',
  data: {
    input: '',
    notesList: [{ }]
  },

  methods: {
    updateNoteList: function (callback) {
      const that = this;
      Note.all((notes) => {
        that.notesList = notes;
        return callback();
      });
    },

    loadFirstNote: function () {
      if (this.notesList.length > 0) {
      this.note = this.notesList[0];
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, such an obvious solution! Sometimes you can't see the forrest through the trees. The escaping was required in the emit function since the template is a string literal. i.e. template: '...';